Sitecore Blank Screen on Custom Site Definition
I am in the process of creating a site definition in Sitecore, but I'm encountering an issue where accessing the hostname (Eurtech.Solutions) results in a blank screen. Additionally, when I navigate to the Sitecore item path (Eurtech.Solutions/sitecore/content/home), I receive raw HTML instead of the rendered content.
Details:
Sitecore Item Location: /sitecore/content/Eurtech
Site Definition Configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="Eurtech.Solutions" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content"
            startItem="/Eurtech"
            hostName="Eurtech.Solutions"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="50MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"/>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hosts File Entry
127.0.0.1   Eurtech.Solutions

IIS Binding: I have added a binding for Eurtech.Solutions in my local Sitecore instance in IIS.

This is my item in Sitecore (It has it's own layout)
Sitecore Item:

Here's the start item

Here's the console output when site is loaded using experience editor

Here's the error when loading the hostname (Eurtech.Solutions)

Here's the raw html when I am going to (Eurtech.Solutions/sitecore/content/Eurtech)

Update:
I can access my images, css and scripts using http://Eurtech.Solutions but can't access the HTML but I can access HTML with http://Eurtech.Solutions/sitecore/content/Eurtech
Also while accessing the HTML from http://Eurtech.Solutions/sitecore/content/Eurtech when going to dev tools and hovering over path to css, images, and scripts it's being resolved as http

Whereas in the console tab it's referring css, images and scripts from https

I believe it has something to do with absolute and relative paths.

have you checked by changing database to master, or try to republish and then check.

Are you sure that you access your website with http? Do you have any errors in the log files?

@GauravAgarwal yes still the same issue

What is your sitename in the content tree,
if your sitename in content tree is Eurtech like  /sitecore/content/Eurtech then if you want to point to the home page.
Then the structure should be like the one below.

Note: startItem should not be Sitename

<!--


<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>

 <site name="Eurtech.Solutions" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            hostName="Eurtech.Solutions"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/Eurtech"
            startItem="/home"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="150MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"
            
/>

    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

I hope this helps :)

I appreciate the help, I have updated the Site definition but still facing the same issue

@YashGupta pls share presentation details of startitem ie) home item , and also share the screenshot of error page and log

Hey I have added the necessary details.

Hi @YashGupta, I dont see anything will be issue, if all site node is configured properly, also you have already checked with the master database also, I hope you will also be verified  site with HTTPS and HTTP which are configured in IIS.
